# Why req.query.name return undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parameters

I tried to get a parameter in my nodeJS server url like this : localhost/?name=Vincent

So, I wrote this code :

```
var request = require('request');
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(fybctuib (req, res) {
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
console.log(req.query.name)  // or juste req.query
```

etc.

And I have undefined in my log when I go on localhost ...
Could you help me, please ? Thank you.

Comment: That code just throws errors. You have misspelt `function`, and you've chopped off the `})` from the end, and anything to make the server actually listen to the request. Please provide a working [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, I can't copy the code

Comment: @VincentBourdon — Then write a test case and **test it** to make sure that it both compiles and demonstrates that problem. Then copy/paste that test case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using Node.js's [`http`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) module. If you look at the documentation for the [`IncomingMessage`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage) object, you'll see that it doesn't have a `query` property. You've probably seen examples of [Express.js](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req) and you're confusing them with the native `http` module.

Either use Express.js, or use `url.parse` as shown in [the `message.url` documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_url).